# Can I access some libraries used by Excel in Perl?

Tags: excel, perl, vba, siebel

We have several macros in Excel. In the references in the excel there is a file called SiebelHtml Type Libary or something to this effect. When this is included in Excel it loads many functions and classes.

For example

```
sApp as SiebelApplication
```

compiles when I include the libary. I have found two files in the directory. They are SiebelAX_Desktop_Integration.exe and SiebelAx_Desktop_Integration.inf.

Does anybody know if I can some manage include the data in these files in a perl script so that I can write a working perl equivalent of the code above. I am not familiar with VBA too much an do not understand what is going on under the hood so to say?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it will be possible 1 to 1.. you will have to rewrite the code to look like the example below:

```
use feature 'say';
use Siebel::COM::App::DataControl;
use TryCatch;

my $app = Siebel::COM::App::DataControl->new(
      {
          user       => 'sadmin',
          password   => 'sadmin',
          host       => 'test',
          enterprise => 'SIEBEL',
          lang       => 'ENU',
          aom        => 'eClinicalObjMgr_enu'

      }
);

my $created_by = '0-1';
try {
    $app->login();

    my $bo = $app->get_bus_object('Account');
    my $bc = $bo->get_bus_comp('Account');

    $bc->activate_field('Location');
    $bc->activate_field('Extension Phone Number');

    $bc->clear_query();
    $bc->set_view_mode();

    $bc->set_search_spec( 'Created By', "='$created_by'" );
    $bc->query();

    if ( $bc->first_record() ) {
        do {
            my $val = $bc->get_field_value('Location');
            say $val;
        } while ( $bc->next_record() )
    } else {
        say 'Could not find the account';
    }
} catch {
    die 'Exception: ' . $app->get_last_error();
}
```

the thing that does the magic is [Siebel::COM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Siebel::COM) perl module.
If you post an example of the Excel script I might be able to help in changing it to Perl equivalent.